# scrapy not selecting the drop down options

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape web site using scrapy. the website has three drop-down menus and website also uses `__VIEWSTATE`. I am able to extract the values of the first drop down ('dcode') but I am not able to extract the options of the second drop-down ('blk').

I am not able to understand why my code is not going inside `parse_blk` function??

I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\WPy-3670\uplist\uplist\spiders\test1.py", line 65, in parse_blk
    dont_filter=True
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 49, in from_response
    form = _get_form(response, formname, formid, formnumber, formxpath)
  File "c:\wpy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 84, in _get_form
    raise ValueError("No <form> element found in %s" % response)
ValueError: No <form> element found in <200 http://sec.up.nic.in/site/PRIVoterSearch2015.aspx>
```

My code so far

```
import scrapy,re
from scrapy.item import Item
#from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

class blkname(Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()

class test1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test1"
    allowed_domains = ["sec.up.nic.in"]

    start_urls = ["http://sec.up.nic.in/site/PRIVoterSearch2015.aspx"]


    def parse(self, response):
        for dcode in response.css('select#dcode > option ::attr(value)').extract():
            #print( response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract_first())
            #print(response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first())
            #print(dcode)
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},
                formdata={
                        'dcode': dcode,
                        '__VIEWSTATE': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
                        '__EVENTTARGET': 'dcode',
                        '__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
                        },
                callback=self.parse_blk,
                dont_filter=True

            ) 

    def parse_blk(self, response):
        for blk in response.css('select#blk > option ::attr(value)').extract():
            #block = response.css('select#blk > option ::attr(value)').extract()
            #print(block)
            #print(response.css('hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first())
            #data = re.findall("__VIEWSTATE| =(.+?);|", response.body.decode("utf-8"), re.S)
            data = re.findall("(?<=__VIEWSTATE).*$", response.body.decode("utf-8"), re.S)
            #print(data)
            #print(block)
            viewstate = str(data).split('|')[1]
            #print (viewstate)
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                        response,
                        headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},
                        formdata={
                                'dcode':response.css('select#dcode > option[selected] ::attr(value)').extract_first(),
                                'blk': blk,
                                '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
                                '__EVENTTARGET': 'blk',
                                '__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
                           },
                    callback=self.parse_gp,
                    dont_filter=True
                )
    def parse_gp(self, response):
       for gp in response.css('select#gp > option ::attr(value)').extract():
            print(gp)
```

Please help me as I am a beginner in this field and I do not have in-depth knowledge of web scraping.

I learnt about scrapy from youtube `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve_0h4Y8nuI&list=PLhTjy8cBISEqkN-5Ku_kXG4QW33sxQo0t` and I have done coding on the basis of `https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/04/20/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-april-2016-edition`

Answer (score 0):

Your parse() should be

```
def parse(self, response):
    for dcode in response.css('select#dcode > option ::attr(value)').extract():
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},
            formdata={
                    'dcode': dcode,
                    '__VIEWSTATE': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
                    '__EVENTTARGET': 'dcode',
                    '__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
            },
            callback=self.parse_blk,
            dont_filter=True
        )
```

[for more detail](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

Comment: I modiefied my form data and included all the parameters but still it is not selecting blocks. If I am trying to print blk id it is returning nothing. As I said my program is not going into parse_blk function...

Comment: if you try print statement above for loop in parse_blk function it is getting executed.

Comment: Ok I will try that, but print command should also print inside loop.

Comment: response is of TextResponse, not HtmlResponse

Comment: change the other methods accordingly

Comment: @ madhav...I have edited my code but still getting errors... can you look into it..

Comment: @gis.rajan you should add the new error to your question because otherwise nobody can help resolve it. The answer did fix the problem your posted.

Comment: I have updated the current code in my question... It is printing block list but not executing parse_blk. Getting error File "C:\WPy-3670\uplist\uplist\spiders\test1.py", line 56, in parse_blk
    callback=self.parse_gp,

Comment: "Dont_filter = True" seems not working. I am calling same webpage multiple times.. Is it the issue???

Comment: you need to pass the correct  __VIEWSTATE coming in the response. currently, it is None.

Comment: Yes u were right I saw the response from scrapy __VIEWSTATE is not within the Input tag. It is there but without any tag. Now looking for a way to extract it.

Comment: I found that `_VIEWSTATE` from the previous page is being used in the next page. Now I have to return it from `parse` to `parse_blk`. Now I will search for how to accomplish this.